# Calculate the number of appointments in a timeslot

Tags: jquery, algorithm, math, time, momentjs

I have a set of doctors. Each one has a specialty (dentist, general, psychiatrist, etc.)
Each specialty has its predefined session (appointment) time allotted, for example:

- Dentist - Appointment time: 30min
- General Ph - Appointment time: 30min
- Psychiatrist - Appointment time: 45min

Each doctor sets his schedule, eg.:

- Psychiatrist - Monday from 08:00 to 12:30
- Dentist - Tuesday from 14:00 to 20:00
- etc.

I'm using jQuery and two (2) BSTimepicker fields to assign the timeslot to each Doctor
http://jdewit.github.io/bootstrap-timepicker/

**Is there any way to calculate (using jQuery or MomentJS lib) the (round)number of appointments a Doctor will be able to attend during his timeslot assigned?**

Thanks a lot in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit, updated

Try

```
var apps = [];
var meds = {
    "psych": {
        "schedule": 4.5,
        "appointment_length" : function() {return this.schedule * 4},
        "appointment_slots" : function() {return this.appointment_length() / 3}
    },

    "dentist": {
        "schedule": 6,
        "appointment_length" : function() {return this.schedule * 2},
        "appointment_slots" : function() {return this.appointment_length() / 2}
    }
};

$.each(meds, function (index, value) {
    apps.push([index, Math.round(value.appointment_slots())]);
    meds.appointments = apps.slice(0, 2);
});
console.log(meds);
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/guest271314/sdxLH/

Comment: Thanks for helping but I'm getting "ReferenceError: psych is not defined". I'm not very familiar with JSON objects